# Rails URL converting to Array path with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, path

I was reading that you can build path urls dynamically building them using arrays in Rails like the following:

```
link_to("Label", edit_admin_user_path(@user))
# same as
link_to("Label", [:edit, :admin, @user])
```

But how would you do this with a path containing arguments? Like the following (its in haml):

```
%td= link_to '', copy_management_director_path(@management, director), :method => :put, :class => 'copy_paste'
```

I picture it being something like [:copy, @management, director]?

**EDIT**

I was reading the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) about dynamicaly building paths. This is good when using polymorphic relations and you want to use the same forms.

Comment: Did you try your guess?

Comment: yeah its not working. :(

Comment: this depends on your routes and only works for a nested resource as far as i know

Comment: i have it nested and no dice. im going to update it again

Comment: Can you try the following? `link_to("Label", url_for([:edit, :admin, @user], director_id: director.id) )`

Comment: This is too late, but I've found url_for([:edit, :admin, @user, {director_id: director.id}]) to work fine